Fit same model to many datasets in Python
Below I demonstrate a workflow for fitting the same model to many datasets in R by nesting datasets by test_id, and then fitting the same model to each dataset, and extracting a statistic from each model.
My goal is to create the equivalent workflow in Python, using polars, but I will use pandas if necessary.
Demonstration in R
library(tidyverse)

SIMS <- 3
TRIALS <- 1e3
PROB_A <- .65
PROB_B <- .67

df <- bind_rows(
    tibble(
        recipe = "A", 
        trials = TRIALS,
        events = rbinom(n=SIMS, size=trials, prob=PROB_A),
        rate = events/trials) |> 
        mutate(test_id = 1:n()),
    tibble(
        recipe = "B", 
        trials = TRIALS,
        events = rbinom(n=SIMS, size=trials, prob=PROB_B),
        rate = events/trials) |> 
        mutate(test_id = 1:n())
)

df


df_nest <- df |> 
    group_by(test_id) |> 
    nest()

df_nest


Define two functions to map over my nested data:
glm_foo <- function(.data){
    glm(formula = rate ~ recipe, 
        data = .data, 
        weights = trials, 
        family = binomial) 
}

glm_foo(df_nest$data[[1]])

fit_and_extract <- function(.data){
    m <- glm(formula = rate ~ recipe, 
        data = .data, 
        weights = trials, 
        family = binomial) 
    
    m$coefficients['recipeB']
}

fit_and_extract(df_nest$data[[1]])

df_nest |> 
    mutate(
        model = map(.x = data, .f = glm_foo),
        trt_b = map_dbl(.x = data, .f = fit_and_extract)
)

test_id  data        model       trt_b                                                                        
<int>    <list>      <list>      <dbl>                                                                  
1        <tibble>    <S3: glm>   0.05606076  
2        <tibble>    <S3: glm>   0.11029236  
3        <tibble>    <S3: glm>   0.01304480  

#Python Section
I can create the same nested data structure in polars, but I am unsure of how to fit the model to each nested dataset within the list column called data.
import polars as pl
from polars import col
import numpy as np

SIMS = 3
TRIALS = int(1e3)
PROB_A = .65
PROB_B = .67

df_a = pl.DataFrame({
        'recipe': "A", 
        'trials': TRIALS,
        'events': np.random.binomial(n=TRIALS, p=PROB_A, size=SIMS),
        'test_id': np.arange(SIMS)
})

df_b = pl.DataFrame({
        'recipe': "B", 
        'trials': TRIALS,
        'events': np.random.binomial(n=TRIALS, p=PROB_B, size=SIMS),
        'test_id': np.arange(SIMS)
})

df = (pl.concat([df_a, df_b], rechunk=True)
    .with_columns(
        fails = col('trials') - col('events')
        ))

df


df_agg = df.group_by('test_id').agg(data = pl.struct('events', 'fails', 'recipe'))

df_agg.sort('test_id')


At this point my mental model of pandas starts to crumble. There are so many mapping options and I'm not really sure how to trouble shoot at this stage.
df_agg.with_columns(
    (
        pl.struct(["data"]).map_batches(
            lambda x: smf.glm('events + fails ~ recipe', family=sm.families.Binomial(), data=x.struct.field('data').to_pandas()).fit()
        )
    ).alias("model")
)

ComputeError: PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: TypeError: cannot use __getitem__ on Series of dtype List(Struct({'events': Int64, 'fails': Int64, 'recipe': String})) with argument 'recipe' of type 'str'
events + fails ~ recipe

Please do not add data examples as images for these reasons. Instead, add the data in a codeblock, either using dput(), or simply as a copy/paste. Thanks

It seems like in Polars, you would do this inside of agg instead of after? e.g. .agg(pl.struct('events', 'fails', 'recipe').map_batches(lambda x: smf.glm(..., data=x.struct.unnest().to_pandas()).fit() - if you print what you're currently sending: lambda x: print(x.struct.field('data').to_pandas() - that doesn't look to be the format the stats function is expecting.

Your R work is incorrect. Note that all the three models in different datasets are the same. This should not be the case

Thank you @Onyambu, there was a typo in my function that I have now fixed.

smf.glm() appears to want a Pandas DataFrame and the given formula can refer to column names.
data = pd.DataFrame(dict(events=[630], fails=[370], recipe=["A"]))

(smf.glm("events + fails ~ recipe", family=sm.families.Binomial(), data=data)
    .fit().pvalues)

# Intercept    4.448408e-16
# dtype: float64

Struct
When you pass a struct through a UDF, you get a Series:
df.head(1).with_columns(pl.struct("events", "fails", "recipe").map_batches(print))

shape: (1,)
Series: "events" [struct[3]]
[
    {630,370,"A"}
]

Series.struct.unnest() will give you a DataFrame (which you can then call .to_pandas() on)
shape: (1, 3)
┌────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ events ┆ fails ┆ recipe │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ str    │
╞════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 630    ┆ 370   ┆ A      │
└────────┴───────┴────────┘

Lists
I don't know R but it seems the difference in this case is that with Polars, creating a List would be the final step in the order of operations.
Once you have a List, it's not as easy to execute such custom functionality for each element.
So we would execute the function at the .agg() stage:
(df.group_by("test_id")
   .agg(
       data = pl.struct("events", "fails", "recipe"),
       glm  = pl.struct("events", "fails", "recipe").map_batches(lambda x: pl.Series(
           smf.glm(
               formula = "events + fails ~ recipe", 
               family = sm.families.Binomial(), 
               data = x.struct.unnest().to_pandas()).fit().pvalues
       ))
    )
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────┬────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ test_id ┆ data                           ┆ glm                    │
│ ---     ┆ ---                            ┆ ---                    │
│ i64     ┆ list[struct[3]]                ┆ list[f64]              │
╞═════════╪════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ [{655,345,"A"}, {674,326,"B"}] ┆ [5.5700e-22, 0.368276] │
│ 2       ┆ [{657,343,"A"}, {658,342,"B"}] ┆ [1.7233e-22, 0.962417] │
│ 0       ┆ [{630,370,"A"}, {657,343,"B"}] ┆ [4.4486e-16, 0.207569] │
└─────────┴────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┘

Polars doesn"t recognize the return value of glm() but wrapping it with pl.Series() inside the callback gives us a list[f64].
Window functions
If you don't actually want to aggregate the DataFrame, you can use .over() instead.
df.with_columns(
    pl.struct("events", "fails", "recipe").map_batches(lambda x: pl.Series(
        smf.glm(
            formula = "events + fails ~ recipe", 
            family = sm.families.Binomial(), 
            data = x.struct.unnest().to_pandas()).fit().pvalues
    ))
    .flatten()
    .over("test_id")
    .alias("glm")
)

shape: (6, 6)
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬─────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ recipe ┆ trials ┆ events ┆ test_id ┆ fails ┆ glm        │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ str    ┆ i32    ┆ i64    ┆ i64     ┆ i64   ┆ f64        │
╞════════╪════════╪════════╪═════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ A      ┆ 1000   ┆ 630    ┆ 0       ┆ 370   ┆ 4.4486e-16 │
│ A      ┆ 1000   ┆ 655    ┆ 1       ┆ 345   ┆ 5.5700e-22 │
│ A      ┆ 1000   ┆ 657    ┆ 2       ┆ 343   ┆ 1.7233e-22 │
│ B      ┆ 1000   ┆ 657    ┆ 0       ┆ 343   ┆ 0.207569   │
│ B      ┆ 1000   ┆ 674    ┆ 1       ┆ 326   ┆ 0.368276   │
│ B      ┆ 1000   ┆ 658    ┆ 2       ┆ 342   ┆ 0.962417   │
└────────┴────────┴────────┴─────────┴───────┴────────────┘


https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/window/


and just add .explode('glm', 'data').unnest('data') to the end to see the results.

@Joe If you don't actually want the lists, you can use a window function df.with_columns(glm=pl.struct(...).map_batches().flatten().over("test_id"))

Amazing! I have to ask, are there any resources you found most helpful to get so fluent in polars?

@Joe I've just learned through usage really. I added some extra details which hopefully help with the mental model side of things.
